# Asignar múltiples teclas a un solo keycode en XKB

Tags: linux

En el archivo **evdev** tengo la lista de asignaciones para cada tecla del teclado. La ruta del archivo es:

```
/etc/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
```

Quiero hacer que si toco la tecla <kbd>5</kbd> aparezca una letra `t`, y que si toco la tecla <kbd>t</kbd>, aparezca la misma letra, es decir, la `t`... Es decir, en los dos casos debe aparecer la letra `t`.

Quiero hacer algo como lo siguiente, como se ve, los dos tienen el keycode `28`:

```
<AE05> =  28; // tecla 5
<AD05> =  28; // tecla t
```

¿Cómo se logra esto esto? Al hacer eso me funciona solo una de las dos teclas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto hay que asignar una tecla con el comando `xmodmap`:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  15 = t T t T tslash Tslash tslash"
```

Cada una de las letras en orden representa:

1. t: `t`
2. T: `shift + t`
3. t: Desconocido
4. T: Desconocido
5. tslash: `altgr + t`
6. Tslash: `shift + altgr + t`
7. tslash: Desconocido